# What's the word regularly used to describe "working from home"?

Tags: words

I've seen a few words in a cursory search:

- [在宅勤務]{ざいたくきんむ}
- テレワーク
- [在宅]{ざいたく}ワーク

but I'm interested in the situation where your usual place of work requires commuting, but you are temporarily working from home just for the day, as opposed to a situation where you are based primarily at home.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a friend how they would ask to work from home due to say bad weather and they said:

天候が悪く、出社困難の為、本日は在宅で仕事をさせていただいてもよろしいでしょうか？

So extrapolating from that if you were describing your own state after getting approval to work from home I believe you would say

今日は在宅で仕事をしている。

Comment: This, though it’s more common to just say 今日は家で仕事する in casual speech. (BTW,  although I’ve heard it, I’d say using から instead of で here is incorrect Japanese and only occurs when people accidently literally translate the English “work from home”.)

Answer (score 0):

I think any of the words you mentioned could be used that way. None of the words you mention specifically imply that a person is always a teleworker.

You can specify that through context, as in the following dialog:

> 松村{まつむら}さんは？

- あっ、**今日{きょう}は**テレワークしていると思{おも}います。
- あっ、**今日は**在宅勤務{ざいたくきんむ}だと思います。

Comment: I'm confused... what is the random「松村さんは？」sentence for?

Comment: I'm trying to show the flow of conversation. So, somebody asks, "Where's Matsumura-san?" or something like that.

Comment: The meaning of "it's just a matter of time-boxing" is unclear to me in this context.  I know what time-boxing is, but what does it have to do with the question or the example sentences?

Comment: Both of the example sentences in the post have 今日は in bold. I was hoping to show that you could make it clear that Matsumura-san was not a regular teleworker by narrowing the time focus of the context. I think that's the situation that the OP is asking about, right?

Comment: In other words... it's not about which word you choose (from the OP), but rather that you provide some time-boxing context which would clear up the ambiguity of whether or not the person in question is a regular or sometimes teleworker.

Comment: Timeboxing is a project management concept. Were you just referring to the mentioning of a particular time in the sentence?

Comment: Yes, I meant that if you limit the time frame of the context, it makes it clear that the person is not a regular teleworker. Maybe I just had that word stuck in my head :P

Answer (score 0):

「今日はリモートで作業します。」would be a natural way to express the situation you describe.